# When is $\Bbb Q(\sqrt p)\subseteq\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]q)$, with $p,q$ prime?

Tags: field-theory

Given primes $p, q$, when do we have

$$\Bbb Q(\sqrt p)\subseteq\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]q)$$

?

At first I tried a linear algebra approach, since in linear algebra, determining when one subspace is inside another is easy, just leading to a system of linear equations. I need to find $x,y,z$ such that $xp^{1/3}+yp^{2/3}+z=\sqrt p$. But to apply linear algebra to this, I'd need to find a basis for the ambient space, say $\Bbb Q(\sqrt p, \sqrt[3]q)$, and trying to do that led me right back to the original question.

Next I tried squaring $xp^{1/3}+yp^{2/3}+z=\sqrt p$, to obtain a linear combination of $(1,p^{1/3},p^{2/3})$ that was equal to $0$. Setting each of the coefficients to $0$ (since $1,p^{1/3},p^{2/3}$ are free vectors) leads to a system of three polynomial equations in $x,y,z,p,q$, but it doesn't look very promising.

How can I tackle this problem? I'm more interested in general methods and ideas on what approach to use. If there's a magic bullet "you just have to see the answer" solution, I'm less interested at the moment (unless there's no other way).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\Bbb Q(\sqrt p)\subseteq \Bbb Q(\root 3\of q)$, then since $[\Bbb Q(\root 3\of q)\colon \Bbb Q]=3$, it would follow that $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt p):\Bbb Q]$ divides $3$. But $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt p):\Bbb Q]=2$, therefore this isn't possible.